# PyQt MainWindow not showing widgets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am making a GUI with PyQt, and I am having issues with my MainWindow class. The window doesn't show widgets that I define in other classes, or it will show a small portion of the widgets in the top left corner, then cut off the rest of the widget.
Can someone please help me with this issue?

Here is some example code showing my issue.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(300, 400)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        names = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3']
        testButtons = buttonFactory(names, parent=self)
        self.hbox.addWidget(testButtons)

class buttonFactory(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, names, parent=None):
        super(buttonFactory, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        for name in names:
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton(name)
            self.vbox.addWidget(btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainWindow()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A QMainWindow has a central widget that is a container in which you should add your widgets. It has its own layout. The layout of the QMainWindow is for toolbars and such. The centralWidget must be set with the `setCentralWidget` method. It isn't enough to just call it `self.centralWidget`

Use the following three lines instead.

```
self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self))
self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.hbox)
```